# Revoke SELECT permission on table

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, privileges

I have the following issue (which seems desperate for me).
I want to have two roles:

1. Role **main_admin** who owns MYTABLE.
2. Role **child_admin** who only can add columns to MYTABLE but can't select from this table (for privacy reason).

My plan was:

1. Add role **child_admin** as subrole to **main_admin** (so, **main_admin** is a group role for **child_admin**).
2. Revoke SELECT privilege from **child_admin**

But rovokation doesn't work because **child_admin** inherits SELECT privilege from **main_admin**. But I must include **child_admin** into **main_admin** because it is the only way to give **child_admin** the ability to alter MYTABLE (is it right?) So, it looks like vicious circle. Is there some way to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can have main_admin define a function with `SECURITY DEFINER` which does the requested ALTER TABLE after validating its input.  Then grant EXECUTE on this function to child_admin (who shouldn't be granted the main_admin role).